# How to obtain a list in a list (aka matrix)?

Tags: calliope, roberta

How to make an n-dimensional datastructure within `lab.open-roberta.org` using `calliope` as system? It seems there is no way to declare a variable as a list within a list. As a workaround one could think of making a list of `String` and then read the characters the string consists of - but it seems there is no way to do that either.
The `Image` is a fine matrix but it's fixed to 5x5 elements.
 Has anybody an idea how to make a more complex datastructure (I know an n-dimensional list can be stored in a one-dimesional list but it's so hard to read that as a human).